# Java StreamTokenizer taking a number and character without whitespace as separate tokens

Tags: java, numbers, inputstream

I'm writing a parser with `StreamTokenizer`. I need an input like `"8a"` to echo an error that a number contains a char. Instead, it prints:

```
NUM: 8 ID: a
```

It seems to be identifying the char as a separate token, even though no whitespace separates them.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of what generates the current output?

Comment: Generally, identifiers **do not** start with numbers, so this might cause a few trouble...

Comment: Here is the code I'm parsing:    
  
{  
 int s;  
 if(z[1] <= 8a)  
  return z;  
 while(r>z)    
 {if (x==2)  
   return x;  
 }  
  
Here's my code:  
  
 switch (token)   
                     {  
                     case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:  
                     {  
                        
                      String s=String.valueOf(st.nval);

Comment: Please show the relevant code snippet.

Comment: What does `if (z[1] <= 8a)` actually mean? If `8a` is not a hex-number, then what is the point of `a`?

Comment: Usagi and Dave, you're both correct, and that's the point. I need the parser to identify the occurrence as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `StringTokenizer`'s `parseNumbers` method to disable special handling of number characters.
Please be aware this might be very risky and otherwise unsuitable.

As per javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#parseNumbers():

```
 * When the parser encounters a word token that has the format of a
 * double precision floating-point number, it treats the token as a
 * number rather than a word, by setting the {@code ttype}
 * field to the value {@code TT_NUMBER} and putting the numeric
 * value of the token into the {@code nval} field.
```

Here comes example - I am not adding 'numeric' attribute to typical characters used in numbers:

```
    final Reader rd = new StringReader("8a");
    final StreamTokenizer tk = new StreamTokenizer(rd) {
        @Override
        public void parseNumbers() {
            // super.parseNumbers(); - by not calling super. I disable special handling of numeric characters
        }
    };

    tk.wordChars('a', 'z');
    tk.wordChars('0', '9');
    while ((tk.nextToken()) != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        if (tk.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD) {
            System.out.println("TT_WORD " + tk.sval);
        }
        if (tk.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
            System.out.println("TT_NUMBER " + tk.nval);
        }
    }
```

outputs:

> TT_WORD 8a

With the above config, you could then get a `String` `8a` and then do `String.contains` to check if a number is present inside.

Comment: This is the direction I was thinking. I may have to implement it on reaching a number then reset the tokenizer parameters after the check, but it should work for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could identify if the current token is a `StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD` and output an error. Check the code snippet below it takes a text with numbers and characters without spaces and outputs an error when it reaches a character.

```
import java.io.*;
public class StreamCharacterChecker{

     public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
        String text = "123458a787";
        Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes())));
        StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(r);
        int token;
        while ((token = st.nextToken()) != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
            if (token == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD){
                System.out.println("Error characters detected!");
                break;
            }    
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I just tried the snippet without the 'a' and still got the error on this one, so I'm unsure on that.

Comment: Sorry There was an error in the condition check it now

Comment: I actually caught that != before and changed it; still wasn't working but somehow now seems to be. That works, thanks!